# Assembly code for converting hex to dec is not working

Tags: assembly, hex, decimal, nasm, multiplication

I have this assembly code (linux 80x86 nasm) that suppose to convert hex numbers to dec:

```
    my_func:
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp    ; Entry code - set up ebp and esp
    pusha           ; Save registers
    mov dword[LC1],0
    mov ecx,dword[ebp+8]    ; Get argument (pointer to string)

start_loop:
    mov ebx,0       ;zero ebx register
    mov eax,16
    mov edx,0
    mov bl, byte[ecx]   ;bl is the curr number
    jmp bl_to_num   ;change it to be a number

continue:
    add dword[LC1], ebx ;dword[LC1] = dword[LC1]+ebx
    inc ecx
    cmp byte[ecx],0
    je  end_func

    mul dword[LC1]  ;dword[LC1]*eax = edx:eax
    mov     dword[LC1],eax

    jmp start_loop
```

dword[LC1] is the argument I return to the C function, and ecx is a pointer to the string received.
the function: bl_to_num just convert the bl byte into a number (a=10, b=11..)
When I run this code with the input 1, I receive output 234.
When I run this code with the input 2, I receive output 250.
and so one..
Where is my error?
Thanks!

EDIT:
this is bl_to_num:

```
bl_to_num:
    cmp bl,'A'
    je  con_a
    cmp bl,'a'
    je  con_a

    cmp bl,'B'
    je  con_b
    cmp bl,'b'
    je  con_b

    cmp bl,'C'
    je  con_c
    cmp bl,'c'
    je  con_c

    cmp bl,'D'
    je  con_d
    cmp bl,'d'
    je  con_d

    cmp bl,'E'
    je  con_e
    cmp bl,'e'
    je  con_e

    cmp bl,'F'
    je  con_f
    cmp bl,'f'
    je  con_f

    sub bl,48
    jmp continue
con_a:
      mov   bl,10
      jmp   continue
con_b:
      mov   bl,11
      jmp   continue
con_c:
      mov   bl,12
      jmp   continue
con_d:
      mov   bl,13
      jmp   continue
con_e:
      mov   bl,14
      jmp   continue
con_f:
      mov   bl,15
      jmp   continue
```

Comment: where is `bl_to_num`?  When you say "hex to dec" do you mean decimal as in floating point (an IEE754 number)?  As in BCD?  A signed integer?  Is the hex input supposed to be a UINT?

Comment: When I say hex to dec, I mean that I receive a string containing (at most 8 digits) 1-9,a-f

Comment: ...and you are converting it also to a string with (0-9) decimal base?

Comment: my function should return a number, in dword[LC1]

Comment: It sounds like you intend to convert to binary integer, not decimal.  (It's an important distinction to make.)

Comment: Can you confirm the contents of `[ebp+8]`?  Clearly you expect it to be `0000 0031` - is that what is there?  Are you sure your input string is null-terminated?

Comment: Are you sure that you're getting ONLY hex digits, and no blanks or tabs or newlines?

Comment: @HotLicks I'm trying to convert to decimal, and I receive a NULL terminated string
J...: When I try only to print the bl content, it is the number expected be. bl is the current digit in each iteration.

Comment: @JaviDorfsman - If you're trying to convert to decimal you're missing half the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your results indicate that your input string contains a linefeed character (0x0A) before the NULL-terminator. So if you input `'1'` you get:

1st iteration:
`LC1 += 1`
`LC1 *= 16 (= 16)`

2nd iteration:
`LC += zero_extend(10-48)` i.e. `LC += 218 (= 16 + 218 = 234)`

Your `bl_to_num` routine could also be simplified a lot:

```
bl_to_num:
  cmp bl,'9'
  jbe digit
  cmp bl,'F'
  jbe already_uppercase
  sub bl,' '
  already_uppercase:
  sub bl,7
  digit:
  sub bl,'0'
  jmp continue
```

**EDIT**: The following works fine for me on my machine (Xeon / Ubuntu 64-bit):

```
format: .asciz "%d\n"

.bss
    LC1:  .long 0

.text
.globl main
.type   main, @function
main:

movl  8(%esp),%ecx   # get argv    
movl  4(%ecx),%ecx   # get argv[1] (argv[0] is the program name)

start_loop:
xor  %ebx,%ebx       
movl $16,%eax
xor  %edx,%edx
movb (%ecx),%bl   

sub  $48,%bl     # simplified bl_to_num that handles only '0'..'9'

continue:
add  %ebx,LC1 
inc  %ecx
cmpb $0,(%ecx)
je   end_func

mull LC1  
movl %eax,LC1

jmp  start_loop

end_func:

movl LC1,%eax
pushl %eax
pushl $format       # push the format string
call printf
addl $8,%esp        # pop the arguments

movl $0, %eax    # return value 
ret
```

**$ gcc -m32 -o hexarg hexarg.s**
**$ ./hexarg 67**
**103**

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
The bl_to_num doesn't work correctly
and I didn't understood what you meant the solution should be...
thanks!

Comment: One solution would be to exit the `start_loop` if you find any character except `A-Fa-f0-9`, not just when a NULL terminator is found.

Comment: I can expect the string to be right.. 
What is not working is the multiplication (in my opinion)

Comment: `mul dword [LC1]` multiplies whatever's in `[LC1]` by whatever's in `eax` and puts the answer in `edx:eax` (you can probably ignore `edx`). You might want to put 10 in `eax` before the `mul` and put `eax` back into `[LC1]` after the `mul`... (what Michael shows in AT&T syntax)

Comment: I saw your answer and tried to translate it to my cpu, without success..

@FrankKotler: this is what I am doing:
  mov eax,16
  mul dword[LC1]
  mov  dword[LC1],eax
Isn't this correct?

Comment: @JaviDorfsman: The bottom line is that the algorithm works, so the incorrect results you get are most likely due to incorrect input. Perhaps you're not getting the pointer to the argument string correctly, or perhaps the string contains extra characters before the NULL terminator on your machine.

Comment: @Michael You were right! My error was comparing the dword[ecx] with 0, when I needed to compare it with 10.
Thanks a lot guys!